# Error: Cannot send value to non-payable function GETH

Tags: ethereum, smart-contract

I call the money (payable) function and pass the money. Error.

Code contract:

```
pragma solidity <0.7.0;

contract contr{

  function money()public payable{
     msg.sender.transfer(5 ether);
  }
}
```

ABI contract:
[{"inputs":[],"name":"money","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"}]

I call the function from the geth console this way:  contr.money.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], value: 50000000000000000000})

also called like this: contr.money.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: contr.address, value: 50000000000000000000}) The error does not chang

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено:

```
Var getData = contr.payinsurence_fee.getData()

eth.sendTransaction ({from: adr, to: adr contract, value: count, data: getData})
```